# go言語の"go build"コマンド実行時に生成されるファイル名について

Tags: windows, macos, go

バージョンgo1.10.3 windows/amd64 および、go1.10.3 darwin/amd64を使用しています。

よくある、Hello world のプログラムを作成し、test.goという名前で保存し、
go build コマンドを使用して、ビルドしたところ、あらゆるサイトでは、mainのあるファイル名のバイナリ(この場合、test.exe)が生成されると書いてあるのですが、私の環境では、そのファイルがあるフォルダ名のバイナリが作成されてしまいます。
例えば、c:\work\test.go というファイルを作成した場合、work.exe ができあがります。
もちろん、できあがったファイルを実行すると、Hello worldは表示されます。

また、go build test.go と打つと、test.exe が生成され、実行も正常です。

チュートリアル通りに動作せず、気持ち悪くて先に進めず詰まっています。
最近の更新で動作が変わったのでしょうか？

ちなみにソースコードは以下の通りです。

<test.go>

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world")
}
```

Comment: 状況がよく分からないのですが、例えば `c:\work` ディレクトリに移動して`go build` とか、もしくは `go build c:\work` などを実行しているという事でしょうか？

Comment: "test.go"以外のファイル名、例えば"sample.go"などにしてからbuildするとどうなりますか？『OS組み込みのコマンドと被る』等の理由により、他のプログラミング言語でもソースコードやコンパイル後の実行ファイルに「test」と名前を付けるのはあまり推奨されません。

Comment: `go help build` を実行すると、"When compiling a single main package, build writes the resulting executable to an output file named after the first source file ('go build ed.go rx.go' writes 'ed' or 'ed.exe') or **the source code directory ('go build unix/sam' writes 'sam' or 'sam.exe')**. The '.exe' suffix is added when writing a Windows executable." と表示されます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。c:\work ディレクトリに移動して go build コマンドを打っています。 go build c:\workとは打っていません。test.goをsample.goにリネームしてみましたが、やはり生成されるのは、work.exeでした。

Comment: `go build` を実行する場合は `go build .` と見倣されますので、ヘルプメッセージに記載されている通り、カレントディレクトリ名である `work.exe` が生成される事になります。

Comment: @templer さん、metropolis さんがご指摘のヘルプメッセージの通りで、`work.exe` ができるのはドキュメント通りに見えます。このドキュメントは Go リポジトリ上の[このファイル](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b3b2f5d9cad01a23622287028fe8c57d59559169/src/cmd/go/alldocs.go#L66)が元ですが、git blame する限りここ数年同じ挙動であったようです。ご覧になっているサイトの更新時間や、そのサイトで使っている Go のバージョンを教えて頂けませんか？　サイト側が間違っているのか、昔の挙動がそうだったのかの切り分けができそうです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。仕様なんですねスッキリしました。チュートリアルサイト(https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.10.3.darwin-amd64.pkg)が hello.go で作成されており、そのファイル名によって実行ファイル hello ができると勘違いしていたようです。よく見ると、ディレクトリ名も hello になっていました。これで先に進めます！ありがとうございました！